# Install all Anaconda packages in air-gap computer

Tags: python, anaconda

I have computer that is not connected to the internet.

I download Anaconda installation wizard , but it is not contains all the packages that Anaconda contains in their website  , and this uncomfortable .

How I can download all the packages that display in Anaconda for offline installation (the size of the installation is not a problem).

Comment: where did you find air gapped installer package?

Answer (score 0):

According to the Anaconda page [here](https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/install/#detailed-installation-information): Obtain a copy of the system appropriate installer, copy to the air-gapped machine, then follow the detailed instructions for you operating system (see links under `"Detailed installation information"`.

Check the environment tab and see if the package you want is part of the environment, but not installed - many are already there. If it is part of the environment, then use the interactive installer to get it installed.

You can also try (from the command line/console) `conda install <package-file-name>.tar.bz2` if you have a particular downloaded package that you want to install. Obviously in this case it needs to be a tar.bz file, but you should be able to modify that for other compression types.

Other environments, such as R are also available in the downloaded, but not installed category.

I think (not sure on this) that things such as Rstudio need to be downloaded separately to install.

Comment: , I familiar with that page, the problem is the installation wizard is not contains all the packages ...., I always need to go back to anaconda website and download manually the package